# How to get DKIM to sign for both, a subdomain and the root domain addresses?

Tags: postfix, domain, subdomain, dkim, digital-signatures

I'm using latest versions of DKIM + Postfix on Ubuntu 20.04
I got the DKIM to sign the e-mails  user@smtpmail.mydoamin.com. However it refuses to sign e-mails that originate from @mydomain.com. Is it possible to sign for both e-mail addresses and if yes, how do I do that?

Below is my opendkim.conf

```
# This is a basic configuration that can easily be adapted to suit a standard
# installation. For more advanced options, see opendkim.conf(5) and/or
# /usr/share/doc/opendkim/examples/opendkim.conf.sample.

# Log to syslog
Syslog          yes
# Added later
SyslogSuccess           Yes
LogWhy                  Yes

# Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
# privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
UMask           007

# Sign for example.com with key in /etc/dkimkeys/dkim.key using
# selector '2007' (e.g. 2007._domainkey.example.com)
Domain          smtpmail.rapidseohost.com
KeyFile         /etc/dkimkeys/smtpmail.private
Selector        smtpmail

# Commonly-used options; the commented-out versions show the defaults.
Canonicalization    relaxed/simple
#Mode           sv
SubDomains      yes

# Socket smtp://localhost
#
# ##  Socket socketspec
# ##
# ##  Names the socket where this filter should listen for milter connections
# ##  from the MTA.  Required.  Should be in one of these forms:
# ##
# ##  inet:port@address           to listen on a specific interface
# ##  inet:port                   to listen on all interfaces
# ##  local:/path/to/socket       to listen on a UNIX domain socket
#
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
#Socket         local:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

##  PidFile filename
###      default (none)
###
###  Name of the file where the filter should write its pid before beginning
###  normal operations.
#
PidFile               /run/opendkim/opendkim.pid


# Always oversign From (sign using actual From and a null From to prevent
# malicious signatures header fields (From and/or others) between the signer
# and the verifier.  From is oversigned by default in the Debian pacakge
# because it is often the identity key used by reputation systems and thus
# somewhat security sensitive.
OversignHeaders     From

##  ResolverConfiguration filename
##      default (none)
##
##  Specifies a configuration file to be passed to the Unbound library that
##  performs DNS queries applying the DNSSEC protocol.  See the Unbound
##  documentation at http://unbound.net for the expected content of this file.
##  The results of using this and the TrustAnchorFile setting at the same
##  time are undefined.
##  In Debian, /etc/unbound/unbound.conf is shipped as part of the Suggested
##  unbound package

# ResolverConfiguration     /etc/unbound/unbound.conf

##  TrustAnchorFile filename
##      default (none)
##
## Specifies a file from which trust anchor data should be read when doing
## DNS queries and applying the DNSSEC protocol.  See the Unbound documentation
## at http://unbound.net for the expected format of this file.

TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key

##  Userid userid
###      default (none)
###
###  Change to user "userid" before starting normal operation?  May include
###  a group ID as well, separated from the userid by a colon.
#
UserID                opendkim
```

Comment: for example, DKIM will sign for root@mailsmtp@domainname.com, but not for root@domainname.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using information in the post below:
[DKIM with same key but different domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/785151/dkim-with-same-key-but-different-domains/785175#785175)

Basically I added a root domain in opendkim.conf:

```
Domain                  smtpmail.rapidseohost.com,rapidseohost.com
```

and than added corresponding domain name TXT record the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

You could also solve this using the `SigningTable` and `KeyTable` options.

Editing your example, I commented out the old `Domain`, `KeyFile`, & `Selector` options. This is not strictly required, since they are ignored when `SigningTable` and `KeyTable` are present:

```
# Sign for example.com with key in /etc/dkimkeys/dkim.key using
# selector '2007' (e.g. 2007._domainkey.example.com)
# These options are ignored if you use SigningTable / KeyTable
# Domain          smtpmail.rapidseohost.com
# KeyFile         /etc/dkimkeys/smtpmail.private
# Selector        smtpmail

# Use tables to map domain (host) names to keys
SigningTable      refile:/etc/opendkim/signing_table
# This doesn’t necessarily need to be a refile, a plain file works most of the time
KeyTable          refile:/etc/opendkim/key_table
```

Then you need to create `/etc/opendkim/signing_table` as a map from wildcard-emails to a key name:

```
# email                         key name
*@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com     smtpmail
*@rapidseohost.com              smtpmail
```

And create `/etc/opendkim/key_table` to map key name(s) to tuples of `domain:selector:key_file`

```
# key name  domain:selector:key_file
smtpmail    rapidseohost.com:smtpmail-2023-07:/etc/dkimkeys/smtpmail-2023-07.private
```

The `domain` portion of the `KeyTable` record can be replaced with a `%`. In that case the “apparent domain” (including any hostname) is substituted. A `%` in the `key_file` protion of the tuple is also replaced by the “apparent domain.” This could allow you to have a single record in the `KeyTable` for multiple domains and simply create key files for each one.

For illustration:

```
all_domains     %:dkim-2023-07:/etc/dkimkeys/%-2023-07.private
```

**NOTE:** It is recommended you rotate your DKIM keys periodically. The recommendation is every 6 months. That’s why I added the year & month on the selector and key files.

When it’s time to rotate, you can

1. Replace this line with the new selector and key file.
2. *Add* the new selector record to your DNS rather than replace the existing one.

Doing so should avoid any race conditions from downstream servers trying to validate on a key you have replaced.